# Classical Probability and Combinatorics

Tags: probability

Shuffle a standard deck of cards and cut it into three piles. What is the probability that a face card will turn up on top of one of the piles?

There are 12 face cards (four jacks, four queens and four kings) in the deck.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Hint: Cutting a shuffled deck into three piles and taking the top cards is just like picking three cards at random. With a theoretically perfect shuffle, this is the same as taking the top 3 cards of the shuffled deck.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in the comments, the split into three decks is just a red herring - the problem is equivalent to just picking the three top cards assuming the deck has been shuffled well.

The probability of getting at least one court card is equal to one minus the probability of the inverse case: getting no court cards at all.

The probability of getting no court cards is fairly easy to compute. First, we have 40 non-court cards to choose from a deck of 52, then 39 non-court cards from a deck of 51 and finally 38 non-court cards from a deck of 50. This makes the probability of getting no court cards in three picks $\frac{40}{52} \times \frac{39}{51} \times \frac{38}{50} = \frac{59280}{132600}$.

This means probability of getting at least one court card is $1 - \frac{59280}{132600} = \frac{73320}{132600}$ which is approximately $0.55$.

Comment: thanks too much for your reply.